# pip3 install opencv-python error on Raspbian

Tags: python, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install `opencv-python` using the following command `sudo pip3 install opencv-python` but I keep getting the following error 
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python`

I tried upgrading the pip with the command `pip install --upgrade pip` and than trying again to install the `opencv-python`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv` ?

Comment: ```Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libpq5 armhf 11.3-1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/postgresql-11/libpq5_11.3-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: maybe run `sudo apt-get update` as the error message says?

Comment: ```Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease                  
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]      
Reading package lists... Done      
E: Repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'stable'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt update`, as is suggested [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=245022)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that there a no `.whl` on pypi for the raspberry architecture. You can also see this on the FAQ section of `opencv-python` [README on Github](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python):

> Q: Pip fails with Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ...?
>
> A: Most likely the issue is related to too old pip and can be fixed by running pip install --upgrade pip. Note that the wheel (especially manylinux) format does not currently support properly ARM architecture so there are no packages for ARM based platforms in PyPI. However, opencv-python packages for Raspberry Pi can be found from https://www.piwheels.org/.

You should always check these pages for additional dependencies or installation notes for special architectures if you are facing any issues.

Note that you can quickly get there by visitng the [Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python) and then selectin the `Homepage` button

Comment: When I do the command to install ```opencv``` it says that its ```Looking for indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://piwheels.org/simple``` so that means the ```pip.conf``` has ```extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple```

Comment: which raspberry-pi (and python version) do you have?

Comment: Rasberry-pi 4 (Python 2.7.16)

Comment: I looked up on the https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv/ and there was no link for ```opencv``` or anything on that site.

Comment: That is because the package you are trying to install is [opencv-python](https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv-python/), which is available but not for python 2.7. Looks like you are stuck to either compile yourself or install using `apt`

Comment: Solved it by installing the ```opencv-python``` with apt, I was having errors with the install (see the comments above) using apt so I had to do ```sudo apt-get clear``` than ```sudo apt-get update``` and fianally the install worked. Thanks for the help